# Trouble inserting polygon to mysql database

Tags: mysql, gis

I tried inserting

```
PolygonFromText("POLYGON((121.44842136764532 31.22119260287111,
                          121.45076025390631 31.221990825071376,
                          121.45402182006842 31.218366658611853,
                          121.45091045761114 31.217054584347302))")
```

as a value into a a field of both type Polygon and of type Geometry.

When I run

```
SELECT PolygonFromText("POLYGON((121.44842136764532 31.22119260287111,
                                 121.45076025390631 31.221990825071376,
                                 121.45402182006842 31.218366658611853,
                                 121.45091045761114 31.217054584347302))")
```

it returns *`NULL`*

My Mysql Version is 5.1.41 - I find the MySql documentation very poor and not user friendly in these cases

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think a Polygon has to close so the last set of coordinates should be same as first one. This will return following

```
SELECT  PolygonFromText("POLYGON((121.44842136764532 31.22119260287111,121.45076025390631 31.221990825071376,121.45402182006842 31.218366658611853,121.45091045761114 31.217054584347302,121.44842136764532 31.22119260287111))");
```

Comment: and if it's not a Polygon you are after then perhaps LineString functions are more what you are needing to use